# PHP - get params from AngularJS $http.get request

Tags: php, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

How does one retrieve the params passed through a $http.get request using PHP?

**This is my controller:**

```
app.controller('phonesCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $scope.make = $routeParams.make;
    console.log($routeParams); // Console displays 'Object {make: "apple"}'
    console.log($scope.make); // Console displays 'apple'

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'tools/get.php',
        params: $routeParams, // Already an object: "{"make" : apple}"
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.phones = response.data;
    });
});
```

**My PHP attempt:** works with $http.post, but something tells me I can't use the `file_get_contents` function to do the same.

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

var_dump($data); // Outputs NULL
var_dump($_POST["make"]); // Outputs NULL
var_dump($_POST); // Outputs empty array

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', 'root');

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM phones WHERE make = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $make);
$stmt->execute();

$result = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

print_r($result);

?>
```

I'm also using the `$routeProvider` service to keep my links clean. At first I realized the console was outputting blank objects so I changed my config to:

```
.when('/get/:make', { // Added /:make
    templateUrl: 'tools/get.php',
    controller: 'phonesCtrl'
})
```

So now my console outputs "apple" when I navigate to /get/apple.

Comment: you could try to put a javascript object instead of a string as a parameter to $http:
var make = {make: $routeParams.phone};

Comment: never try making json manually ... it is error prone and much simpler to let `$http` do it for you

Comment: Why do you ask about `file_get_contents`? I guess PHP told you, that it expects a `string` (file name) as the first parameter and you're passing an `array` instead (`$_GET`). It doesn't make a sense. BTW as the name suggests, function `file_get_contents` returns you a content of file specified by the filename in the first parameter as a `string`. But you're just sending a GET parameter, there are no files at all, why would you like to use that function? You already get the GET parameter as a string in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I was just playing around at this point. I had `file_get_contents("php://input")` at first because that's what I'm doing for my `post` request and it works. I wasn't exactly sure what I was doing at this point.

Comment: @PatrickKelleter Thank you for pointing that out, I was thinking it was a lot more difficult than it had to be.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the tip, I will definitely practice this rule from here on in.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP use

```
$_GET["make"]
```

To get the params.

Answer (score 0):

If you read PHP $_POST documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) you can find

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** [what you are using] or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

What you are trying to do is to pass a GET request with POST parameters. You ether pass it like this `www.yoursite.it/page.php?name=Matteo` and then you take the variable with `$name = $_GET['name']` or you pass in your way but in `POST` so like this:

```
$http({
method: 'POST', //CHANGE THIS FROM GET TO POST
url: 'tools/get.php',
params: {
    name: 'Matteo' //USE PROPER JAVASRIPT OBJECTS
},
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
})
```

And then you get the variable with `$name = $_POST['name']`

Comment: I've updated the question to include the `$routeProvider.config` and corrected the URL for it to include `/:param`. I was getting an empty object prior to adding that. I've also attempted to pass the params as a post and retrieve them with `$_POST` and I've also tried to pass the params through the url `tools/get.php?make=apple` and tried to retrieve them using `$_GET` and I still output `NULL` or `empty array`. What could I be missing?

Comment: Can you see in your dev console if the params are passed in this way: make=Apple in the form data panel ? Maybe post a screenshot